# How to install PeaZip on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, archive

I want to install PeaZip for a specific purpose, which I can't fulfill with any other archive manager. I downloaded and installed it by using both dpkg -i & Gdebi. Now I can't start it, because I can't find the launcher.  Please provide a solution.

Comment: answer outdated, mark the other

Comment: updated answer since newer packages seem to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason some of the older GTK debs are configured for the KDE desktop. They include a desktop icon, but install it to the KDE directories. I fixed this by just linking the desktop file in the correct directory.

Just run `sudo ln -s /opt/kde3/share/applications/kde/PeaZip.desktop /usr/share/applications/`.

Alternatively, you could just copy the shortcut with `sudo cp /opt/kde3/share/applications/kde/PeaZip.desktop /usr/share/applications/`

Newer versions found on their [download](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html) page seem to have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can download an Ubuntu package for PeaZip from their website:

- http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html

You'll probably want one of the GTK2 versions unless you're using KDE.